# Auto refresh data in dataTables, Cannot set properties of null

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an issue with aiyp refreshing a dataTables table. When I run the script below I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'data')
    at sa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:37)
    at Tb (jquery.dataTables.min.js:108)
    at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:108)
    at s.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:100)
    at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:108)
    at Object.reload (jquery.dataTables.min.js:103)
    at Object.<anonymous> (flights.php:1405)
    at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)`
```

Script Example

```
var recordid;
var flightno;
var airlinename;
var io;
var airlinecode;
$("#update_flight").submit(function(event) { //2
        recordid = $('#RecordID').val();
        hotelid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid'];?>";
        flightno = $('#FlightNo').val();
        airlinename = $('#AirlineName').val();
        io = $('#EditIO').val();
        airlinecode = $('#EditAirlineCode').val();
        airlineprefix = $('#EditAirlinePrefix').val();
        $("#EditShowBar").show();
        var status = 1;
        console.log("RECORD ID ", recordid);
        var form = $('form')[1];
        console.log("Form", form);
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append("RecordID", recordid);

        $(".progress-bar").animate({
        width: "100%"
        }, 2500);

        $.ajax({
        url: "update-flight.php",
        data: formData,
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        }).done(function(response) {
        $('#edit_data_Modal_2').modal("hide");
        $('#userTableAllFlights').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        });
});
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Does `userTableAllFlights` exist when this runs?

Comment: @Twisty Hi and thanks for your reply. userTableAllFlights is the id of a DIV where the rows are displayed. I have .DataTable().ajax.reload(); running in other scripts without any issues.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The Code makes now sense. You never use the response so where should the data come from?

Comment: @Thallius most likely, the Datatables are configured with an AJAX Source. See: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: `userTableAllFlights ` is a div or a table? Define your table like this: `const table = $('#tableId').DataTable({options});` Then call the reload function like this `table.ajax.reload();`

Answer (score -1):

add your datatable js code inside to $(function () {})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).